# Equilibrium solution for a heat equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Find the equilibrium solution of

$$
u_t(t,x) = u_{xx} (t,x) + x^2,  \ 0<x<L\\
u(t,0) = 0,\  u(t,L) = 0
$$

I know that the equilibrium solution must satisfy: $[u_e(x)]' = 0 \ \forall t$. It must also satisfies the boundary conditions. I'm not sure what the first step is though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At equilibrium, $u_t(t,x) = 0$ for $x \in [0,L]$.

The steady state solution $U(x)$ satisfies

$$U_{xx} (x) + x^2=0,  \ 0<x<L\\
U(0) = 0,\  U(L) = 0.$$

Integrating we get

$$U(x) = -\frac1{12}x^4 + C_1x + C_2.$$

Applying the boundary conditions we find

$$C_1 = \frac1{12}L^3,\ C_2 = 0,$$

and

$$U(x) = \frac1{12}[L^3x - x^4].$$

Comment: did you mean $U_{xx} (x) + x^2 = 0$ on the third line?

Comment: @user90593:  Yes -- thanks -- I corrected above.